# PHP PDO query issue

Tags: php, mysql

I'm switching my project over to PDO and I'm having problems with the following code. It does NOT throw an error, but also does NOT insert into the database. I've been reading up on PDO and I've looked into `DebugdumpParams()`. I added `$result->debugDumpParams()` and the page does not load.

Do I need to use `BindParam()` after `prepare()`, before `execute()` to be able to debug?

```
public function CustomerInsert($name, $street1, $street2, $city, $state, $zip, $phone_area, $phone, $email, $notes, $leadtype, $rating, $newsletter, $frequency)
    {
$q = "INSERT INTO customers VALUES('', :name , :street1 , :street2 , :city , :state , :zip , :phone_area , :phone , :email , :notes , :newsletter , :leadtype , :frequency )";

try{
$result = $this->connection->prepare($q); 

$result->execute(array(':name'=>$name, ':street1'=>$street1, ':street2'=>$street2, 
                                ':city'=>$city, ':state'=>$state, ':zip'=>$zip, ':phone_area'=>$phone_area, 
                                ':phone'=>$phone, ':email'=>$email, ':notes'=>$notes, ':newsletter'=>$newsletter, 
                                ':leadtype'=>$leadtype, ':frequency'=>$frequency));
}
catch (PDOException $e) 
{  
   throw new Exception('Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage());
 }
```

Comment: Turn error reporting on

Comment: How do I do that? Error reporting in PHP? Is it possible to do that on a per-file basis?

Comment: And also look at what's returned by `$result->ErrorInfo()` and `$this->connection->ErrorInfo()`

Comment: yeah, you probably have a warning trailing somewhere. Silly question of mine I hope you won't mind, but are you sure it is possible to specify an insert without adding the fields before the VALUES(...) part?

Comment: (As a wild stab in the dark, I'd suggest removing the intial `''` in your INSERT - is that where the auto_number ID field is?)

Comment: Calling an `INSERT` statement without specifying the columns is bad form. If/when the schema changes, this code will malfunction horribly.

Comment: You could try it with `$this->connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` - makes it harder to miss errors

Comment: Ok. I will redo my query to specify the columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query doesn't look malformed, so my guess would be that the number of values does not match the number of fields in the table. You can fix this by specifying the fields in your query:

```
$q = "INSERT INTO `customers` 
      (`name`,`street1`,`street2`,`city`,`state`,`zip`,`phone_area`,`phone`,`email`,`notes`,`newsletter`,`leadtype`,`frequency`)
      VALUES(:name , :street1 , :street2 , :city , :state , :zip , :phone_area , :phone , :email , :notes , :newsletter , :leadtype , :frequency )";
```

But you'd be able to see the error from MYSQL if you [turn error reporting on within PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php), e.g.:

```
$this->connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Comment: Ahhh, sweet, that is throwing an error now with a column. I think I can figure it out now. Will update in a minute.